# How to move the focus to another app in appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm writing test automation for an app. The app launches the phone dialer with a specific phone number when clicking a button. I want to return the phone number to my code and return it to the app.

I'm using appium 1.21 and java.

I've tried to use this code:

```
    androidDriver.activateApp("com.android.phone");
    System.out.println(androidDriver.findElement(MobileBy.id("digis")).getText());
    androidDriver.activateApp("com.app.test"); //return to the app from dial
```

but i'm getting an error :

> Encountered internal error running command: Error: Cannot activate
> 'com.android.phone'. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
> error: 'Command '/Users/idoa/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P
> 5037 -s ce051605bd453d2502 shell monkey -p com.android.phone -c
> android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1' exited with code 252'; Stderr:
> 'args: [-p, com.android.phone, -c, android.intent.category.LAUNCHER,
> 1]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Key presses on appium are done by

`driver.press_keycode(code)`

[All  required codes can be found here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

- 187 - KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH

Try this, not sure whether it solves